# How to setup a VPN tunnel using WireGuard?

Tags: vpn, remote-access, home-server, wireguard

How do I setup a VPN tunnel using WireGuard?

I need to securely link my home server with my laptop (both machines running Windows 11).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a detailed, tested procedure to install and configure WireGuard on your machines to allow remote connection via VPN tunnel.

Please note: this procedure is tested and working in my environment and on my machines, but there might be other factors to consider depending on your specific setup.

**1. *On both machines:* download WireGuard**

Download WireGuard from official website and install it on both machines. Admin rights required.

**2. *On server machine:* configuration**

The *server* tipically is the "remote" machine you need to access. In my scenario, this is a lab / home server used for software developing and testing.

1. Click on *Add empty tunnel* from options in *Add tunnel* button.
2. Add a name for new tunnel.
3. Write down the *private key* and *public key* generated by WireGuard.
4. Add an IP address for your interface. This will be the IP address of the machine when connected remotely. You have to use CIDR notation. In this example, I'll use 20.0.0.1/24.
5. Specify listening port number (use an high port number, like between 49000-65000). In this example, I'll use 49313.
6. Specify MTU value (minimum transfer unit; google it if you need more information and help about how to determine it; mine is 1472).

You should now have something like this:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ***your_server_private_key***
ListenPort = 49313
Address = 20.0.0.1/24
MTU = 1472
```

**3. *On client machine:* configuration**

Create a new empty Notepad file as follow:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey =
Address = 

[Peer]
PublicKey = 
PresharedKey = 
AllowedIPs = 
Endpoint =
```

Now we can start filling some information in it.

1. Under *Interface* section, specifiy in *Address* an available address in the range we used in server configuration. I'll use 20.0.0.2/24.
2. Under *Peer* section, specify in *Endpoint* the public IP of server (or router) you need to access, followed by the port number choosen before. Try searching the internet if you need help finding your public IP, and remember: do not post it publicly.
3. Under *Peer* section, copy in *Public key* the server's public key.

You should now have something like this:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey =
Address = 20.0.0.2/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***your_server_public_key***
PresharedKey = 
AllowedIPs = 20.0.0.0/24
Endpoint = your.public.ip.with:portnumber
```

Now we need to generate client keys (public, private and preshared).

Use *Command Prompt* and the following commands to generate needed files (change working directory if you want):

1. wg genkey > peer2.key
2. type peer2.key | wg pubkey > peer2.pub
3. wg genpsk > peer2.psk

Three different files will be generated in your current prompt working directory.

**Important note:** Keep these files secure! Anyone with these files can remotely connect to your server!

Now we can copy contents to the appropriate configuration field:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ***content from file peer2.key***
Address = 20.0.0.2/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***your_server_public_key***
PresharedKey = ***content from file peer2.psk***
AllowedIPs = 20.0.0.0/24
Endpoint = your.public.ip.with:portnumber
```

Save the Notepad file as *peer2.conf* and be sure to keep secure this file, too.

Open WireGuard and click *Add new tunnel from file*, then pick up the peer2.conf file you just created.

**4. *On server machine:* add the client to server configuration**

Finally, we need to specify that the client is authorized to connect to our server.

Go back to WireGuard in your server and add a *Peer* section in your tunnel configuration:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ***your_server_private_key***
ListenPort = 49313
Address = 20.0.0.1/24
MTU = 1472

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***content from file peer2.pub***
PresharedKey = ***content from file peer2.psk***
AllowedIPs = 20.0.0.0/24
```

**5. *On client machine:* change network type to *Private***

In order to get all services working correctly (FTPs,RDPs, etc), you may need to change *Network type* from *Public* to *Private*.

This setting has to be set on client machine.

To do so, open a *Powershell* window and use the following command to get the list of all *Connection Profiles*:

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile
```

Find the WireGuard connection profile - it has the name you assigned *in client side* (open WireGuard and check).

Use this command to change the network to *Private*:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias 'wg1' -NetworkCategory 'Private'
```

Change *wg1* with the name you chose.

**6. Firewall / router configuration**

Last but not least, you need to allow port forwaring on your firewall / router. Simply add a rule (or port association) specifying local IP (your server's private IP) and port (49313 in this example). Different routers may require slightly different procedures, but you should easily find these settings in any router.

That's all! Feel free to comment and ask questions if you need help or if you want to improve this simple guide.